# How it can be "The name sounds familiar to me."?

Tags: sentence-usage

> The name **is known** to me. (a medium level of knowing) - OK
>
> The name **is familiar** to me. (a high level of knowing) - OK
>
> The name **sounds known** to me.(it seems that is a medium level of knowing) - OK
>
> The name **sounds familiar** to me. (it seems that is a high level of knowing) - ???

I know that "it sounds familiar" is a common expression but I can't understand its logic if we know the difference  between **"is familiar" - it's true - and "sounds familiar" - it seems it's true**. So, how it might be logically that we use "The name sounds familiar to me."? Because, if we try to analyze those words one after another, it looks like: It seems  that the name has a high level of knowing for us. And that looks illogically because I can understand "The name sounds known to me." [maybe, they mix up it] but not "The name sounds familiar to me." [because how could they mix up the well-known name?].

Comment: Your "levels of knowledge" are a bit fanciful. But actually, I suspect most native speakers would rarely if ever use anything except the final *That name **sounds familiar** to me* - almost always meaning *I think I've heard that name before, but I can't remember the actual **person***. On rare occasions someone might say *That name is known to me* - more explicitly making the point that *I've **definitely** heard that name before (but I don't know the actual person).* If you *did* know who the name referred to, obviously you'd refer to the person, not the name.

Comment: sounds known=buzzer.

Comment: **Sounds known** is definitely not idiomatic. Either you know a name or you don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use 'sounds familiar' to express tentative recognition.

> Person A: Have you heard of Peter Williams?
> Person B: The name sounds familiar, where might I know him from?
> Person A: He is an actor.
> Person B: Ah Yes! He was in a TV crime drama, wasn't he?
> Person B: Yes, he was in episode three of *Thrilling Murder Stories*.
> He played the detective.

Also sarcastically to express definite recognition:

> Person A: I found Mother drunk under the table last night. She said
> she had accidentally drunk a whole bottle of sherry.
> Person B: That sounds familiar.